# How to delay the graph redraw?

Tags: dc.js

I have a "graph" that is an input field used to filter the other graphs (filter to only take into account the data that contains the text entered into the field.

It works fine, but when you are looking to filter on a word (eg "test", it will filter on t, then te, then tes, then test) and redraw the graphs 4 times and it feels a bit sluggish, especially on smartphones.

Is there a way to delay drawing the graphs for a few ms to be sure an extra letter isn't typed?

Ideally, I'd want to filter for each letter and draw the fast graphs (eg display the dataCount) and wait a bit before drawing the others (eg. the bubble chart or the linechart that seems to be more cpu bound).

Is there an easy way to do it?

Related question: would it make sense to add that input field "filter graph" as a new graph type into dc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first part of the question, the functionality you are looking is called "throttling". There's an [implementation of it in underscore](http://underscorejs.org/#throttle) and in lodash, among other places.

(Don't use `dc.events.trigger`, [because it's a debounce](https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/issues/630).)

As for drawing just some of the charts, you could have your "filter graph" set the crossfilter dimension filter and then redraw just some of the charts, and then wait for the throttled event to redraw the rest of them, since `redrawAll` really is just iterating over all the charts.

There is nothing built-in to manage these kinds of sub-groups, though, so you would have to keep your own lists of charts.

I.e. something like (probably munging d3 and jquery syntax here, but you get the idea):

```
function fast_redraws() {
    [chart1,chart2,chart3].forEach(function(c) { c.redraw(); });
}
function slow_redraws() {
    [chart4,chart5,chart6].forEach(function(c) { c.redraw(); });
}
var throttle_slow_redraws = _.throttle(slow_redraws, 100, {leading: false});
input.on('change', function() {
    dimension.filter(input.val());
    fast_redraws();
    throttle_slow_redraws(); // throttling makes this okay
})
```

And yes, it would be great to have a simple input widget like this in dc.js - I'm not sure how to deal with the fast/slow redraws in a general way, though. It could package up some of the wisdom that goes into answers [like the responses to this issue](https://github.com/square/crossfilter/issues/107).

Comment: fast vs. slow: what about having the throttled function that by default that simply calls dc.redrawAll() and an on("change") event that is (optionally) used to do the fast_redraw (and not throttled)

Comment: Hmm. Maybe if the chart registry were just an event dispatcher, [as hinted here](https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/issues/910), then it would be easier? Well, this really isn't the place to discuss future designs. If you have an idea, please raise it in an issue or on the user group.

Comment: ok, PR on your way, trying to add meaningul tests, but might share the code first